# Ring homomorphism and ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ and $R'$ be rings and let $\phi: R\mapsto R'$ be a ring homomorphism and $N$ an ideal of $R$.

Show that $\phi[N]$ is an ideal of $\phi[R]$, and give an example to show that $\phi[N]$ need not be an ideal of $R'$.

Let $N'$ be an ideal of either $\phi[R]$ or R', and show that $\phi^{-1}[N']$ is an ideal of R.

I just started learning ideals so I am having a lot of trouble with this. I know that the kernel of $\phi$ is an ideal, but I don't know how I can use this.

Comment: I guess you mean $\phi(N)$ need not to be ideal of $R'$.

Comment: that's correct, sorry.

Comment: $\phi$ is from $R$ to $R'$ , how can you talk about $\phi(R^{'})$

Comment: sorry I made lots of mistakes typing this out, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show that $\phi(N)$ is an ideal we must show that it is an additive group and closed under multiplication in $\phi(R)$

> Showing $\phi(N)$ is an additive group

Identity

So as $0\in N$ and $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism we have that $\phi(0)=0\in \phi(N)$

Closure

Now take $x,y\in \phi(N)$ then by definition of $\phi(N)$ there must exists $a,b\in N$ such that $\phi(a)=x$ and $\phi(b)=y$. Now as $N$ is an ideal we have that $a+b\in N$ and so $\phi(a+b)\in \phi(N)$, then as $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism we have that $\phi(a+b)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)=x+y\in \phi(N)$.

Inverses

If we have $x\in \phi(N)$ then by definition there must be an $a\in N$ such that $\phi(a)=x$ now as $N$ is an ideal we have that $a^{-1}\in N$ and so $\phi(a^{-1})\in \phi(N)$. Now as $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism we have that $\phi(a^{-1})=\phi(a)^{-1}=x^{-1}\in \phi(N)$

So we have that $\phi(N)$ is an additive subgroup of $\phi(R)$

Now to show that it is an ideal we have to show that if we have $r\in \phi(R)$  then $r\phi(N)\subset \phi(N)$ and $\phi(N)r\subset \phi(N)$

> Showing $\phi(N)$ is closed under multiplication of $\phi(R)$

Now if $r\in \phi(R)$ then there must be an $r'\in R$ such that $\phi(r')=r$

Then as $r'N\subset N$ we have that $\phi(r'N)=\phi(r')\phi(N)\subset \phi(R)$ (same argument for $r$ on the right)

> Example of image of an ideal is not an ideal

We can define the inclusion map $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ and then take an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ say $3\mathbb{Z}$ then $f(3\mathbb{Z})$ is not an ideal in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Suppose that it was, then noting that $1\not\in f(3\mathbb{Z})$. But by the definition of ideal we must have, $\frac{1}{3}\in\mathbb{Q}$, $\frac{1}{3}\times 3\in f(3\mathbb{Z})$ which gives a contradiction.

Note: as $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field then it has only the two trivial ideals so it follows directly from this.

Another example is given here: [The image of an ideal under a homomorphism may not be an ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166703/the-image-of-an-ideal-under-a-homomorphism-may-not-be-an-ideal)

Comment: just reading the first couple lines -- is it clear that $\phi(R)$ is a ring? I mean, to show we have an ideal of a ring we need to first establish that we have a ring at all.

It's probably true that the image of any ring homomorphism is always a ring, but I just want to be sure. Never hurts in math.

Comment: @terribleatmath as $R\lhd R$ if we show that $\phi(N)$ is an ideal then this is the same as showing $\phi(R)$ is a ring, pretty much. I mean it is basically what I have done above- you should be able to adapt it pretty easily

Comment: It's easy to check directly: $\phi(a)\phi(b)=\phi(ab),\phi(a)-\phi(b)=\phi(a-b)$.

Comment: @hmmmm: if you find an example such that $\phi(N)$ is not ideal of $R^{'}$ then your answer is complete. :)

Comment: that's interesting, thank you. i'll read this carefully and let you know how it goes!

Comment: @mesel done :) ...

Comment: @hmmmm: so your answer is complete,took upvote from me :)

Comment: This is fantastic thanks a lot. It makes sense now. and that's a great example too.

I'm now trying the last part, to prove that $\phi^-1[N']$ is an ideal of $R$ for $N'$ an ideal of either $\phi[R]$ or $R'$.

is the inverse of a homomorphism a homomorphism? I was first thinking I could simplify this so it doesnt have to be a lengthy proof like last time by using that the kernel of a ring homomorphism is an ideal, however the kernel of the inverse map is obviously injective..

Comment: How are you defining $\phi^{-1}(N')$? If $N'\cap Im(R)=\{0\}$ what is $\phi^{-1}$ defined as? More specifically as $\phi$ is not an isomorphism is does not have a naturally defined inverse

Comment: I think it means the inverse image of $\phi$. So $\phi^{-1} : Im(\phi) ---> R$ afaik

Comment: @terribleatmath what is afaik? Ok but from this definition we only have that $\phi^{-1}$ is defined on the image of $\phi$. So in your question when you say that $N$ is an ideal of $\phi(R)$ or $R'$, we may apply $\phi^{-1}$ to ideals of $\phi(R)$ otherwise this as this is where it is defined

Comment: @terribleatmath in order to show this we simply need to show that $\phi^{-1}:Im(\phi)\rightarrow R$ is a ring homomorphism and then apply what we have already done, do you see? Any ideas how to proceed to show that $\phi^{-1}$ is a ring homomorphism?

Comment: afaik is "as far as i know

well, we need zero goes to zero, one goes to one,  and additive and multiplicative distributivity.. well, I don't think I know anything about the inverse image of phi.. so i dont know where to start..

Comment: @terribleatmath yes we do, for example as $\phi(0)=0$ that gives that $\phi^{-1}(0)=\phi^{-1}(\phi(0))=0$. The same argument runs for $1$.

Comment: @terribleatmath then we can do a similar thing for additive homomorphism property. That is: if $a,b\in Im(\phi)$ then $exists x,y\in R$ such that $\phi(x)=a$ and $\phi(y)=b$ then $phi^{-1}(a+b)=\phi^{-1}(\phi(x)=\phi(y))$. Then as $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism we have that $(\phi(x)+\phi(y))=\phi(x+y)$ and so...

Comment: @terribleatmath it is just running essentially the same argument over and over that things in the image of $\phi$ must have a pre-image in $R$. For these sorts of questions when you say "I don't think I know anything about the inverse image"- you do. You need a bit more confidence to stick with it for longer. You know its the inverse image of a ring homomorphism, so the only thing that you can use is that information- you then just need to play around with it for a while and you will get there :)